# select specific data from all (around 5000 tables) tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

It is very bad idea creating lots of tables in single database. I understand it now.
So i want to fix this by creating new single table. so i want to fetch all rows of all tables into single table.

I searched everywhere but there isn't a solution, so need help

Here is my Situation:

Each table has following columns

```
id
name
flag
poststatus
```

I can run below query to get data from two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE poststatus = '2' UNION SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE poststatus = '2';
```

But this is for only two tables i have to run query for almost 5000 tables.

is there any better way to fetch all data in single query or any other idea ..

Thank you.

Comment: ooh just a minute small fix..

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP at hand (like the tag suggests) you can create a small script that creates all the 5000 SELECT statements for you like:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5000;$i++)
    $sql.="INSERT INTO combined (name, flag, poststatus) SELECT name, flag, poststatus FROM table".$i." WHERE poststatus=2\n";
file_put_contents('combine.sql', $sql);
```

poststatus = '2';

Comment: How can i fetch all names in database. ($i)

Comment: You can do a SHOW TABLES in PHP and then loop over the result.

Comment: can you write this query fully "INSERT INTO alldata SELECT * FROM table".$i." WHERE ...\n"

Comment: I've updated the query assuming you don't want the IDs to collide and the poststatus=2 condition still holds.

Answer (score 0):

Execute replacing the schema and the `like` expression.

```
set group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
select 
    concat('select * from ',
    group_concat(table_name separator ' where poststatus = ''2'' union select * from ')
    ) as query
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'database_name' and table_name like 'table%'
```

Comment: you query can work because i have all tables containing "user" in table name so it is easy to fetch all data. can you tell me what to put in table_schema?/

Comment: @AasimMohd Try the database name.

Comment: @AasimMohd Did you change the `like` expression to `'user%'` or whatever matches? Show a sample of a table name.

Comment: yeah it is working it creates that whole union query .. thanks.

Comment: there is one problem: In phpMyAdmin window it is not showing full query in the end there is just blank like this "select * from table8 where poststatus = '2' union select * from table9 where poststatus = '2' union select * fro  " it is just showing 1038 characters in full text. i tried exporting but results are same. please help.

Comment: @AasimMohd Do it as a prepared statement as in my edited answer.

Comment: error is "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fro' at line 1 "

Comment: @AasimMohd Try with the first statement I just added.

Comment: again error " #1193 - Unknown system variable 'group_contact_max_len' "

Comment: the query has been successfully executed but it does not output results in phpmyadmin i got message in execute query line like "EXECUTE query;# Rows: 1600" . how can i view result in phpmyadmin. Thank you so much for replying my all questions

Comment: @AasimMohd I added the `create table` statement so the result of the select will be inserted in a new table.